# How to use htaccess back-reference variables for RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to match PHPSESSID with query string part (?session_id=b0300e9317e626da2c3f9a45e28b5106) of a URL. But i am not able to do this. I think the second rule does not seem to work. What's my wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !PHPSESSID=(\w+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:%{QUERY_STRING} ^PHPSESSID=(.*?);:(?!.*?session_id=\1).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: Your 2 rules don't really make sense. The first says `If there is no PHPSESSID then ...` and the second says `If you can match the PHPSESSID and <something else> ... then`. I'm pretty sure these cannot both be true, which means your rewrite will never happen. Why do you think you need the first `RewriteCond`? What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Missing `OR` flag on first `RewriteCond` and both conditions are broken. It should be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(?:^|\s)PHPSESSID= [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE};;%{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|\s)PHPSESSID=([^;]+).*?;;(?:.*?&)?session_id=\1(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=302,L]
```